# How to aggregate list in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a set of containers each with a set of items. The MongoDB document for a container looks like below. How do I list all the items in all the containers with the container name in each item?

```
{
    "Container": 28392
    ...
    "Items": [
        {
            "ItemName": "Foo", 
            ...
        }, 
        {
            "ItemName": "Bar", 
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
[

     {
          "ItemName": "Foo",
          "Container": 28392 
           ...
     }, 
     {
          "ItemName": "Bar",
          "Container": 28392 
           ...
     },
     {
          "ItemName": "Baz", 
          "Container": 52892 
           ...
     }

 ]
```

Would this be possible with some kind of an unwind? If so how would I aggregate this?

Comment: What is the question? Perhaps show expected output and most definitely show some attempt at solving the problem. Happy to assist those who show some effort, and this honestly should not be stated to someone who has frequented this site for as long as your self. Could show a lot more effort.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am new to MongoDB & NoSQL. I think this would involve some kind of unwind, but not sure how to aggregate.

Comment: That's okay. Have you even looked at [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and what it does? The output from that simple step alone is not *exactly* what you state as *expected*, but it's pretty close. Or at least it should be pretty close for anyone familiar with with "denormalized" results from a SQL RDBMS. With that in mind, if you understand SQL, then [SQL to Aggregation Mapping Chart](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) is certainly worth a look.

Comment: Can you please check my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `unwind` you can use `project` stage to do what you want:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Items"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      Container: "$Container",
      ItemName: "$Items.ItemName"
    }
  }
])
```

Playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/H-aWx07pCDt

**Or if your mongodb version is equal or greater than 4.2**, you can use `replaceWith`  with `mergeObjects`, to get all fields in items array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Items"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        {
          Container: "$Container"
        },
        "$Items"
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Playground:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/E5KqFlNq1CL

Input:

```
[
  {
    "Container": 28392,
    "Items": [
      {
        "ItemName": "Foo",
        "ItemDesc": "Foo desc"
      },
      {
        "ItemName": "Bar",
        "ItemDesc": "Bar desc"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Container": 28392,
    "ItemDesc": "Foo desc",
    "ItemName": "Foo"
  },
  {
    "Container": 28392,
    "ItemDesc": "Bar desc",
    "ItemName": "Bar"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a query like this?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Items"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$Container",
      "All Items": {
        "$push": {
          "ItemName": "$Items.ItemName",
          "Container": "$Container"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Here's a link to a demo of the query - https://mongoplayground.net/p/QDxr-2VUa_f